# Finding the exact location in the code using Firebug

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have a web page and when a user hovers an image, a new image opens up on the right hand side with some links in it.

Basically, I want to find where those links are defined in the code. (I am using ColdFusion). I can see the HTML being created dynamically by using Firebug's *Script* panel or the dev tools in Firefox and Chrome. Is there an easy way to determine where exactly I can find what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go directly to the code for a specific element on the page, just right-click it and choose *Inspect Element* in Chrome or Firefox. 
If you use Firebug, you just choose *Inspect Element with Firebug* instead.

**Update based on comment**

You cannot go from the rendered version in the browser to the actual code on your server. Assuming that you can access your files through an FTP client, you will have to navigate to that file manually.

Where they are located is depending on the structure of the page. If you have a simple HTML website without an CMS, it is usually located according to the **same structure as the page's URL**. If the url is *example.com/category/page.html* the file will be located in *the root folder -> a folder named 'category' -> a file named page.html*. Open that file and you will find the code.

To go to a specific line of code that you have looked up with the *Inspect Element* feature. I usually just search for it within the code editor. You can probably find a search feature in your editor in the menu.

Comment: Inspect element will tell me where exactly that link is defined i nthe HTML code but I want to know in which folder that HTML code is written so that I can make changes.

Comment: Because this question comes up very often, there is even an [FAQ section](https://getfirebug.com/faq#Where_is_the_source_shown_inside_the_HTML_panel_located) at getfirebug.com answering this. Jens already answered this question in detail, I just want to add that the contents you're seeing on the page could even come from the database. So you won't necessarily find the line inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to completely understand your question. But the way that I find specific areas of code on the page is via the inspector tool with Google Chrome. Right click on an element (like the link in question) and select "Inspect element".